# Populating data in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a JUnit test case for a short method and I think I am setting all the required fields to prevent any `NullPointerException` but `filters` is always `Null` due to which my test doesn't go inside the loop. `ILocalPostProcessFilter` is an interface that is implemented by `BaseExceptionPostProcessFilter` which is an abstract class and this abstract class is extended by a concrete class `MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter`. I don't have any asserts yet so please ignore it.

Method under test:

```
protected  <T extends BaseServiceResponse> T processLocalPostProcessFilters(T resp, Response cResp) throws EISClientException
{
    List<ILocalPostProcessFilter> filters = config.getLocalPostProcessFilters();
    if(filters == null)
        return resp;
    T bResp = resp;
    for(ILocalPostProcessFilter filter : filters)
    {
        bResp = filter.postProcess(resp, cResp);
    }
    return bResp;
}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
    public void testProcessLocalPostProcessFilters() throws Exception {
        TestClass baseClient = new TestClass(new ClientConfiguration(), "serviceURL");

        CatastropheServiceResponse catastropheServiceResponse = new CatastropheServiceResponse();
        CatastropheResponse entity = new CatastropheResponse();

        catastropheServiceResponse.setContentLength(10);
        catastropheServiceResponse.setContentType(ContentType.XML);

        entity.setSource(ResponseSourceEnum.CATASTROPHE);
        entity.setTransactionId("01234");

        catastropheServiceResponse.setEntity(entity);

        Response response = mock(Response.class);

        ILocalPostProcessFilter filter = new MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter();
        ((BaseExceptionPostProcessFilter) filter).setHttpStatusCode("200");
        ((BaseExceptionPostProcessFilter) filter).setCondition(ConditionOperator.OR);

        List<ILocalPostProcessFilter> listFilter = new ArrayList<>();
        listFilter.add(filter);

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setLocalPostProcessFilters(listFilter);

        baseClient.processLocalPostProcessFilters(catastropheServiceResponse, response);

    }
```

Not sure what needs to be done to populate filters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are adding filters to a different instance of `ClientConfiguration` than the one used when newing up a `TestClass` which you are calling `processLocalPostProcessFilters` on

Comment: It worked by adding the same instance of `ClientConfiguration`. Thank you so much.